# Regularization in TensorFlow using tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected

Tags: tensorflow

`fully_connected` has a named parameter called `weights_regularizer` which accepts the regularizers provided by `tf.contrib.layers`, however it is not clear the trainers are able to find these regularization loss tensors or if we have to manually add them to the total loss.

Could somebody provide an example of regularization using `fully_connected`?

Answer (score 4):

The regularizer outputs are added to a collection called `REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` (the layer calls [model_variable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py#L244) with the regularizer).

You have to add the content of `REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` to your loss yourself. To get all the tensors in the `REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` collection, use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)`.